# ARM cortex Architecture Code execution

Tags: controller, arm, execution

I have got a question the STM32F407 uC or more over about the cortex-M4 in general.

So how is code performed on the arm? Is every single instruction loaded from Flash and executed or is it stored in the RAM. Or does it buffer and what's about self modifying code are there 2 separate Adress spaces for RAM and CODE(Flash)

hopefully somebody can give me an explanation how this is handled by default.

Answer (score 2):

From [some ST marketing page](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1169/SS1577):

> > ... these MCUs leverage ST‘s 90 nm NVM technology and ST’s ART Accelerator™ to reach the industry’s highest benchmark scores for Cortex-M-based microcontrollers with up to 225 DMIPS/606 CoreMark executing from Flash memory at 180 MHz operating frequency.

So it executes from flash (it should be part of the address space) by default but I'm sure you can copy some code to `ram` and run from there as well however your mcu's `flash` size is much more compared to its `sram`.

Second part of your question can be answered by saying ARM architecture uses same address space for instructions and data but they have different buses / caches (due to performance reasons) - making it harder to have self-modifying code solutions.

Comment: As the core appears to be clocked at 180Mhz, it rather looks as though the flash is as fast as the embedded SRAM on these parts, so not a great deal to be gained from copying code into SRAM.  Furthermore, there isn't very much of it either.

Comment: it runs from flash, and you control a divisor to keep the flash from being overclocked (the flash is running slower than the processor, so at times the processor has to wait).  Despite stating harvard architecture, you can run from sram, at sram speeds.